# MySQL - Finding a user's first referrer

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a creative query request, with a few examples of my own.

I have a table that logs user's hits with the following fields:

- `id` unique value for each logged hit
- `referrer` text value of a URL
- `date` integer value of unix timestamp
- `unique` a string identifying users uniquely (md5 of IP + salt, basically)

(Note that I realize that using "`unique`" as a field name ended up being a terrible design choice, but putting it in backticks has helped avoid any issues...)

I would like a query which returns a list of `unique`s and their first referrer.

Comment: You mean _first_ by date or by hit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking the first referrer by date for each user you can do something like that:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_hits
SELECT
  `unique`
, `date`
, `referrer`
FROM log_table
ORDER BY `date` ASC
;

SELECT
  `unique`
, `referrer`
FROM tmp_hits
GROUP BY `unique`
;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a hit_id field, you'll have to use the pair of (`unique`, `date`) as a row identifier.  You should be able to get what you are looking for with something like this.

```
SELECT `referrer` FROM `hits` h1 INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT `unique`, MIN(`date`) FROM `hits` GROUP BY `unique`) h2
ON h1.`unique` = h2.`unique` AND h1.`date` = h2.`date`
GROUP BY `referrer`
```

If you have a primary key you didn't mention, like hit_id, it gets a bit shorter and saves you from the rare case that two hits occur from the same user in the same second:

```
SELECT `referrer` FROM `hits` h1 INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT MIN(`hit_id`) FROM `hits` GROUP BY `unique`) h2
ON h1.`hit_id` = h2.`hit_id`
GROUP BY `referrer`
```

In both cases, the last GROUP BY is just to remove dups in your final result set.

Comment: I'm looking for something that runs without picking a particular user - it should return one referrer per user, and that referrer should be the one with the smallest date (or id) value.

Comment: Then the second [edited] query should work for you.  The inner query will get you the hit_id of the records that represent each user's first hit, the outer query will join with that to get you the referrer for each user's first hit.

I'd be curious to know how the performance compares between this and the TEMP TABLE idea.